# Android Emulator Shows Message "Unfortunately Application has stopped"

Tags: android-emulator, monkeytalk

I am trying to run monkeytalk recording for external app(Connect2field).But it doesnt record anything in monkeytalk IDE and if we open this app on android emulator,then it shows message "Unfortunately Connect2field4+ has stopped"

Please tell me clear steps how I can record external android app.
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in java build path , go to order and export tab, "AspectJ Runtime Library" and android Libraries are ticked. I also faced same issue. After order and export it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You will find detailed steps here:

http://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-getting-started/install-agent/android

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please provide a summary of links that you post about, as this helps in case the link is no longer valid.